# Silverlight Get Records Problem

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am usinq MySqlServer Domain Service and ADO.NET Entity Model for Silverlight Database works.

When I get the records from DataBase my grid get the columns name but there is no row no data. Sometimes my grid is invisible after I give ItemSource

this is my codes.

```
var q=DomainService.getItemQuery();
LoadOperation<TypeOfItem> c = Sk.Load<TypeOfItem>(q);
datagrid.ItemSource=c.Entities;
```

What Can I do? i try get the 500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked that your LoadOperation is completing without errors?  I.E. is c.Entities null?

Comment: sory my query was wrong now it is workinq.How much records can i load a datagrid normally?because i have 37000 records is it a problem.Can i load the grid when it scroll?

Comment: I don't think the 'default' DomainService calls will do that for you, but I am sure there is guidance out there for how to do that.